# There are 5 cubes, each cube has a different color and on each cube the numbers 1-6. Someone throws the cubes

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are 5 cubes, each cube has a different color and on each cube the numbers 1-6. Someone throws the cubes. How many combinations are there, in which the set of the numbers that appear on the cubes has exactly 3 objects? 
I was thinking: we need 3 different numbers and then 2 numbers that appeared already, so - $6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot1\cdot1$, then multiply by all the ways to order the colors ... so the answer $=5!\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4$
What do you think?

Comment: That counts several such combinations in different orders. $1,2,3,3,3$ for example, is counted gotten by generating $2,1,3$ then two threes, or $3,1,2$ and then two threes. Even worse for $12233$.

Comment: Perhaps you could first try to work out how many ways you can partition a group of $5$ objects into $2$ groups of $2$ and $1$ group of $1$? And then consider the one other case, that is partitioning a group of $5$ objects into $2$ groups of $1$ and $1$ group of $3$

Comment: Thanks @moorish & ThomasAndrews . So $\binom{5}{3}\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4$ ?

Comment: You missed @moorish's point. You chose the three dice to match, then the value of the match, then the values of the other two.  You missed the case of two pair.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd expand on my comment as an answer, so here it is:

Consider the $5$ dice of different colors as $5$ distinct objects.

There are only two possibilities if the numbers that appear on the cube constitute a set of $3$ distinct numbers.

The first possibility is a $(2,2,1)$ result, such as $(1,1,2,2,3)$ and the other possibility is a $(3,1,1)$ result such as $(1,1,1,2,3)$.

Now, lets say we are only interested in an arbitrary combination of $3$ numbers from the possible $6$, maybe $1,2,3$.

We want to partition our $5$ dices into $3$ groups, with a positive number of dice in each group. Each group in this scenario is simply one of the numbers in our set of $3$.

The first way of doing this, as said before, is the $(2,2,1)$ scenario.

Suppose the dice are $G$, $Y$, $R$, $P$, $W$ .

One possible grouping is then $G Y | R P | W $, this means the green and yellow dice are $1$ the red and purple dice $2$ and the white dice rolled a $3$.

Clearly there are $5!$ different ways of arranging these distinct objects in a row, but in order to exclude equivalent combinations, like $Y G | P R | W$ which is simply the same as the state shown above, we need to divide by $4$ as for any combination, there are $4 = 2! *2!$ equivalents which will be over-counted. This comes from the $2$ groups of $2$ dice.

Similarly there will be $3!$ combinations counted as distinct with the $(3,1,1)$ case coming from the group of $3$ dice, which we will need to divide by.

So for the $(2,2,1)$ scenario, we have $\large \frac{5!}{4}$ different combinations.

As said before, the $(3,1,1)$ case is very similar, we have $\large \frac{5!}{3!}$ different combinations, by applying the same logic we applied above.

So in total, for any arbitrary $3$ numbers, we have $\large \frac{5!}{4} + \frac{5!}{3!} = 50$ different combinations.

But there are $6\choose 3$ different possibilities for our $3$ numbers, so applying the fundamental counting principle , in total we should have:

${6\choose 3} * 50 = 1000$ different possibilities.

Please correct me if I have made any mistakes.

EDIT 1: I realized that I need to multiply my answer by three, as for any partition of the $5$ objects, there will be three different possibilities concerning the largest group, namely, the largest group of either $3$ or $2$ dice may roll the numbers $x$, $y$ or $z$. Before, my answer only accounted for dices of the largest group in the partition rolling some fixed number in the $6\choose3$ combinations. So the correct answer should be $3000$.

You should take a look at Andre Nicolas's answer, as it is both correct and more efficient than this.

Comment: The basic cases approach you used is fine. My answer, using a different technique, is $\binom{6}{3}(3^5-3\cdot 2^5+3)$.

Comment: That looks interesting, do you mind explaining your technique? By putting it into my calculator it seems your answer is ${6\choose 3}(150) = 3000$

Comment: OP asked a similar question today, as part of a set. I answered, fairly briefly, there.

Comment: Ah yes, I've found it, I'll take a look, thanks!